# Extract params fro url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From the url below how can I extract the value 1?

```
`http://localhost:3000/category/products/1`
```

I tried params[:id] and params[:products][:id] but got nothing.

Comment: Try `params[:product_id]`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make suitable change in your `routes.rb` file? You need to include something like

```
GET /category/products/:id , ...
```

to make it work with `params[:id]`.

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

The direct answer to your question is to fix your `routes.rb` file

As per the Rails [RESTful routing structure](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), you should be able to use a named scope to achieve this:

```
#config/routes.rb
scope 'category' do
    resources :products
end

#/category/products/1 -> params[:id]
```

---

**Nested**

What I recommended above should fix your problem directly

However, I think you're trying to achieve `nested` resources. If this is the case, you should use something like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :categories do 
    resources :products
end
```

This will allow you to do:

```
#categories/:id/products/:product_id
```